# How does `find . -name *foo*` work?

Tags: bash, find

I thought the wildcard `*` in the command `find . -name *foo*` is replaced by bash, and yet the command works unless `*foo*` matches something in the current directory, then it doesn't. It's confusing.

Comment: Note: If you replace the `find . -name *foo*` with `find . -name '*foo*'` it will allow the wildcard matches to work as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If bash can't find a match, it passes the literal string to the application with `*`s unexpanded. For example:

```
$ ls
foo

$ cat /tmp/test
echo $1

$ /tmp/test *foo*
foo

$ /tmp/test *bar*
*bar*
```

`bash` expanded `*foo*` because it matched, but passed `*bar*` directly because it didn't. The `nullglob` option will tell bash to resolve non-matching patterns to the empty string instead:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ /tmp/test *bar*

$
```

Comment: A little comment to say that zsh has not the same default behavior, it returns an error: `zsh: no matches found`.

Comment: zsh has `no_nomatch` to trigger this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

If you want `find` to get the unexpanded string, then you could quote it or protect the wildcards with backslashes.

```
$ ls
foo

$ cat /tmp/test
echo $1

$ /tmp/test '*foo*'
*foo*

$ /tmp/test \*foo\*
*foo*
```